# Headers disappear

Tags: header-footer

Hope you are all fine.

when using fancy,

I have set

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}%
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\nouppercase\sc{\chaptername\ \large{\thechapter}\ \normalsize{\leftmark}}}}
\fancyhead[L]{MY NAME}
```

But the header disappears every time the pdf compiles the first page of a chapter.

How can I keep the header in the Chapter 1 Introduction page as well as in ALL chapters pages?? Thank you in advance.

Comment: chapter openings in most classes use `\thispagestyle{plain}` to drop the headers. (note you have given no information about your document class)  Unrelated but `\sc` is not defined by default and does not take an argument, use `\textsc{...}`  also `\large{\thechapter}` should be `{\large \thechapter}`

Comment: the fancyhdr package allows you to redefine the plain style  (look for `fancyplain` in the manual)

Comment: Sorry, it is true, my document class is book.

Comment: Dear David Carlisle, thank you for all your comments. I appreciate very much.

Answer (score 1):

Redefine the `plain` style and use it.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{MY NAME}
  \fancyhead[R]{%
    \nouppercase{%
      \scshape\footnotesize\chaptername\ %
      \large\thechapter\ %
      \normalsize\leftmark
    }%
  }%
  \fancyfoot[L]{\thepage}
}
\fancyhead[L]{MY NAME}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Note that `\nouppercase` is a command taking an argument, so your (deprecated and obsolete) command `\sc` did essentially nothing).

To the contrary, `\footnotesize`, `\large` and `\normalsize` don't take an argument.

Fix the footer definitions to your liking. I guess you're using `oneside` printing. But then the choice of placing the page number on the left is curious.

[image]